# C# GUID for different platform

Tags: c#, mmc

I'm now writing a snap-in for MMC3.0, it should support both x64 and x86 platform, but the GUID should be different. 
In C++ I know there are macros like _WIN32, but I can't find something like this in C#.
My target is to let the code looks like

```
#ifdef _WIN32
[SnapInSettings("x86_guid")]
#else
[snapInSettings("x64_guid")]
#endif
```

x86_guid and x64_guid should be constant.

I have been looking around for a while, but no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new solution / project platform for a 64-bit build and then define different GUID-s for the different platforms. You'll then build 2 DLL-s of your MMC snap-in: one for 32-bit platforms and one for 64-bit platforms.

In `Build->Configuration Manager` create a new build platfom (for example `x64`) and then go to the `Build` in `Project properties` to define a new symbol for your `x64` build target. This would be something like `_WIN64`. You can leave the `Platform target` dropdown as `Any CPU`, just make sure that the 64-bit MMC loads your _WIN64 build version. (I'm not familiar with how to set up MMC snap-ins so I don't know what this involves.)

Once you do the above configuration steps, you can now pretty much duplicate your C++ code in C# to check for build target:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
[SnapInSettings("x64_guid")]
#else
[snapInSettings("x86_guid")]
#endif
```

The GUID-s would be hardcoded strings so they'd be constants.

Comment: thanks for your reply.i don't know if i understand it correctly, if i follow the way, i need maintain 2 copy for a same code. it's too hard, at last i decided to undefine all TRACE marcro for x86 configuration and define TRACE for all x64 configuration no matter release or debug. use the TRACE flag as platform macro.

Comment: @JoeyYu No, you don't need to maintain 2 copies of the code. You need to have 2 copies of the resulting DLL, but this would be the same with C++ as well. You'll just have a single code base and you'll have to build it twice - once for x86 and once for x64.